# openSUSE remove kernel module

Tags: opensuse, kernel-modules, mouse

I recently installed openSUSE. I have a problem with the mouse left click. I had the same problem in Debian but when I removed the `psmouse` module everything started working perfectly. I tried the same in openSUSE but I get this error:

```
FATAL: Module psmouse is builtin
```

The touchpad is working perfectly.

I use the Genius USB mouse in my KDE desktop. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: The `psmouse` is not a module in OpenSUSE and it seems it is compiled and built in in the kernel. So you have to rebuild you kernel without it.